# How to get HTML element coordinates using C#?

Tags: c#, html, mshtml, web-crawler

I am planning to develop web crawler, which would extract coordinates of html elements from web pages. I have found out that it is possible to get html element coordinates by using "mshtml" assembly. Right now **I would like to know if it is possible and how to get only necessary information (html,css) from web page, and then by using appropriate mshtml classes get *correct* coordinates of all html elements?**

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean coordinates as in pixels from top and left edges of browser window? As this renders slightly differently in different browsers, I doubt that it's even possible. (And also, it would seem more or less impossible to define which coordinates are "correct", too...)

Comment: It might render slightly differnet, but only one way is correct (assuming you have a CSS file which eliminates browser default values.)

Comment: Coordinates, in pixels, might be even in respect to parent node. What I meant about correct coordinates, is that rendered html file without css file would give different coordinates of elements. What I don't know if it is possible to use HTMLDocument class to analyze web page without having to manually download it, and to do it as efficient as possible.

Comment: Maybe simplified question would be more clear - How to get coordinates of html elements produced by mshtml rendering engine from remote web page as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these c# functions to determine element positions. You need to pass in a reference to the HTML element in question.

```
public static int findPosX( mshtml.IHTMLElement obj ) 
{
  int curleft = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent != null ) 
  {
    while (obj.offsetParent != null ) 
    {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
  } 

  return curleft;
}

public static int findPosY( mshtml.IHTMLElement obj ) 
{
  int curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent != null ) 
  {
    while (obj.offsetParent != null ) 
    {
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
  } 

  return curtop;
}
```

I get HTML elements from the current document like so:

```
// start an instance of IE
public SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass ie;
ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
ie.Visible = true;

// Load a url
Object Flags = null, TargetFrameName = null, PostData = null, Headers = null;
ie.Navigate( url, ref Flags, ref TargetFrameName, ref PostData, ref Headers );

while( ie.Busy )
{
  Thread.Sleep( 500 );
}

// get an element from the loaded document
mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass document = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)ie.Document);
document.getElementById("myelementsid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how one could do this in C# as it's not my language of choice but it could be done using Javascript, particularly using jQuery's [offSet() function](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset).

Comment: Could you explain this method a little bit more, what steps should be done in order to obtain information that I need?

Comment: It's just a case of calling the function on the DOM elements you want the offset for. There is a few examples in that link.