# How to get HTML element coordinates using C#?

Tags: c#, offset, ihtmldocument2

This is related to ([How to get HTML element coordinates using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547614/how-to-get-html-element-coordinates-using-c))

The answer given here is quite good. However, opening up a full instance of Internet Explorer seems like overkill if you're trying to process a good deal of information from within your own spider.

Has anyone found/encountered/thought of a way to to do this using the underlying interface structures of IE (Like [IHTMLDocument2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28VS.85%29.aspx) and it's brethren).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean coordinates as in pixels from top and left edges of browser window? You need to perform a render of the HTML content to find that out, and IE8 is as good a way to do that as any.

Comment: Just because you don't like the answer doesn't mean this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547614/how-to-get-html-element-coordinates-using-c.

Comment: John - thanks for replying. Consider it less of a dupe and more of an expasion.

Robert - Also - thank you for posting. I'm wondering if there isn't unneeded overhead in doing a full render in IE8. I've been doing some research into "Headless Browsers" which will do the rendering without calculate the rendering the window. I'm curious if this is faster. There are a few mozilla based projects that are headed in this direction. More as soon as I finalize my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers don't agree on per-pixel rendering in every situation.  CSS Compliance, rounded corners, transparency support and padding bugs (*I'm looking at you, IE6*) are just a few.

The only way to reliably do this is to open a browser like the question you linked and figure it out that way.  Even then, know that your results may not be the same as another browser will see it.

Site note:  Different DPI & zoom settings for accessibility also will affect this, there are tons of variables in what people see.  Mac font rendering also differs, so those users will usually see things slightly different as well.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks - Re: the above. I'm wondering do you think something like Crowbar (http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar) would perform better then opening the page up in IE? I'm actually popping it open in IE8 now and accessing the MSHTML object tree to get at the positioning data. This works well enough for the sort of analytics I'm doing, but it's *dog* slow. I haven't given Crowbar a play yet (will tonight) but do you think the div positions will be rendered (albeit with deviation from what's rendered in IE - I only need estimates). 

Thanks!